# How to insert list items using JavaScript Object Model in SP

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-object-model, client-side-rendering

I am trying to insert list item's value through JavaScript object model in SP. When I call `set_item('fieldname','Title')`, it throw error "**c.set_item is not a function**". How to successfully Insert a List Item?

Here is my code:

```
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 
oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');
oListItem.update();
```

Comment: Why are you writing `this.oListItem` in one line and `oListItem` in the other? are they the same? What does `oListItem` look like, before you call `set_item()` ?

Comment: @Mavani Please provide your load and execute query code as well. Also, is there any required field other than "Title" ?

Comment: @SohailShaikh, have you tried the code snippet below ?

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT I know the below code will add the item successfully. I was just trying to check the full code OP (@Mavani) is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createListItem, 'sp.js');
function createListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

[image]

Reference:

[How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14))